# OpenLayers 3 - Recuperar Polígono via ajax para editação

Tags: openlayers-3

Tenho uma página que possui um mapa do **OpenLayers** (*versão 3*). Nesse mapa, eu tenho inserido algumas interações, como: Criar e alterar polígonos. Bem, até aqui, tudo certo.

Eu crio os polígonos, que são salvos numa variável array e ao mesmo tempo são gravados no banco de dados para posterior consulta ou alteração. Ainda na mesma página, sem fechá-la ou efetuar qualquer *refresh* da página, eu seleciono o polígono que eu quero alterar, e ele é redesenhado no mapa e consigo alterá-lo e salvá-lo novamente sem problemas.

Contudo, o problema está aqui, ao fechar a página e acessá-la novamente, o sistema busca os polígonos que já foram salvos no banco, e ao selecionar para fazer a edição, ele redesenha o polígono no mapa, mas eu não consigo modificá-lo.

Eu queria ajuda para saber o porque que eu não consigo alterar.

Código do mapa:

```
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
    // create a vector layer used for editing
    var vector_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      title: 'Vetores',
      visible: false,
      name: 'my_vectorlayer',
      source: vectorSource,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#ffcc33',
          width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 7,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ffcc33'
          })
        })
      })
    });

    var overlayGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Layers',
        layers: []
    });

    mapPrincipal = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      renderer: 'canvas',
      //renderer: 'webgl',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Group({
            'title': 'Mapas',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Water color',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                        layer: 'watercolor'
                    })
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'OSM',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: true,
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                new ol.layer.Group({
                    title: 'Satellite and roads',
                    type: 'base',
                    combine: true,
                    visible: false,
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
                        }),
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'hyb'})
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Satellite',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
                })
            ]
        }),
        overlayGroup,
        new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Dimensionamento',
            layers: [vector_layer]
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 12,
        center: ol.proj.transform([-49.086656570434556, -26.486168960979036], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
      })
    });
```

Código para criação e alteração:

```
      var Modify = {
    coords: '',
    init: function() {
        this.select = new ol.interaction.Select();
        mapPrincipal.addInteraction(this.select);

        this.modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: this.select.getFeatures()
        });
        mapPrincipal.addInteraction(this.modify);

        this.setEvents();
    },
    setEvents: function() {
      var selectedFeatures = this.select.getFeatures();

      this.select.on('change:active', function() {
        console.log('Feature ativa!');
        console.log(selectedFeatures);
        selectedFeatures.forEach(selectedFeatures.remove, selectedFeatures);
      });

        this.modify.on('modifyend',function(e){
            //Draw.setCoord(e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates());
            elevatorias[chave].coords = e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        });

        $(document).on('keyup', function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 46) {
            // remove all selected features from select_interaction and my_vectorlayer
            selectedFeatures.forEach(function(selected_feature) {
              var selected_feature_id = selected_feature.getId();
              // remove from select_interaction
              selectedFeatures.remove(selected_feature);
              // features aus vectorlayer entfernen
              var vectorlayer_features = vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures();
              vectorlayer_features.forEach(function(source_feature) {
                var source_feature_id = source_feature.getId();
                if (source_feature_id === selected_feature_id) {
                  // remove from my_vectorlayer
                  vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(source_feature);
                }
              });
            });
          }
        });
    },
    setActive: function(active) {
      this.select.setActive(active);
      this.modify.setActive(active);
    },
    setStyle: function(hex) {
        /*
        vector_layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#000' }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#fff', width: 2
                })
            })
        }));
        */
        var hexToRBAColor = ol.color.asArray(hex);
        vector_layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
            feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'rgba(' + hexToRBAColor[0] + ', ' + hexToRBAColor[1] + ', ' + hexToRBAColor[2] + ', 0.2)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: hex,
              width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: 7,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: hex
              })
            })
          }));
        });
    },
    clearMap: function() {
      vector_layer.getSource().clear();
      if (this.select.getFeatures()) {
        this.select.getFeatures().clear();
      }
    }
  };
  Modify.init();

  var Draw = {
    coords: '',
    lineString: '',
    kmRedeTotal: 0,
    color: '',
    wgs84Sphere: '',
    init: function() {
        /* Declaração de variáveis */
        coords = new Array();
        lineString = new Array();
        kmRedeTotal = 0;
        wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);

        mapPrincipal.addInteraction(this.Polygon);
        this.Polygon.setActive(false);
        mapPrincipal.addInteraction(this.LineString);
        this.LineString.setActive(false);

        this.Polygon.on('drawend', function(event) {
          //coords[coords.length] = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
          elevatorias[chave].coords = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
          marker_layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(e) {
              if (ol.extent.containsCoordinate(event.feature.getGeometry().getExtent(), e.getGeometry().getCoordinates())) {
                clientes.push({nome: e.get('name'), id: e.get('id'), consumo: e.get('consumo')});
              }
          });
        });

        this.LineString.on('drawend', function(event) {
            lineString[lineString.length] = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            console.log(lineString);
            for(var i = 1; i <= (lineString[(lineString.length-1)].length-1); i++){
                kmRedeTotal += Draw.CalculateDistance(lineString[(lineString.length-1)][(i-1)][0], lineString[(lineString.length-1)][(i-1)][1], lineString[(lineString.length-1)][i][0], lineString[(lineString.length-1)][i][1]);
            };
            console.log(kmRedeTotal);
        });

        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>';
        button.setAttribute("title", "Desenhar Polígono");
        var button2 = document.createElement('button');
        button2.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>';
        button2.setAttribute("title", "Alterar Polígono");
        var button3 = document.createElement('button');
        button3.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>';
        button3.setAttribute("title", "Deletar Polígono");
        var button4 = document.createElement('button');
        button4.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>';
        button4.setAttribute("title", "Mudar a cor");
        button4.setAttribute("id", "btnChangeColor");
        var button5 = document.createElement('button');
        button5.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="font-size: 0.6em;"></i>';
        button5.setAttribute("title", "Calcular Kilômetro de Rede");
        button5.setAttribute("id", "btnCalcKmRede");

        button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Draw.setActive(true, 'Polygon');
            Modify.setActive(false);
        }, false);

        button2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Draw.setActive(false, 'Polygon');
            Modify.setActive(true);
        }, false);

        button3.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Modify.clearMap();
        }, false);

        button4.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            $(this).ColorPicker({
                onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                color = '#' + hex;
                $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                Modify.setStyle(color);
            }});
        }, false);

        button5.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Draw.getActive() && Draw.setActive(true, 'LineString');
        }, false);

        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = 'rotate-north ol-unselectable ol-control';
        element.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        element.appendChild(button);
        element.appendChild(button2);
        element.appendChild(button3);
        element.appendChild(button4);
        element.appendChild(button5);

        mapPrincipal.addControl(new ol.control.Control({
            element: element
        }));
    },
    setCoord: function(value) {
        coords = value;
    },
    getColor: function() {
        return color;
    },
    getCoord: function() {
        return coords;
    },
    getKmTotalRede: function() {
        return kmRedeTotal;
    },
    getLineString: function() {
        return lineString;
    },
    LineString: new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: vector_layer.getSource(),
      type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('LineString')
    }),
    Polygon: new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: vector_layer.getSource(),
      type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon')
    }),
    getActive: function() {
      return this.activeType ? this[this.activeType].getActive() : false;
    },
    setActive: function(active, type) {
      if (active) {
        this.activeType && this[this.activeType].setActive(false);
        this[type].setActive(true);
        this.activeType = type; //'Polygon';
      } else {
        this.activeType && this[this.activeType].setActive(false);
        this.activeType = null;
      }
    },
    CalculateDistance: function(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2) {
        return wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(Draw.Transform(lng1,lat1),Draw.Transform(lng2,lat2));
    },
    Transform: function(lng, lat) {
        return ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    }
  };
  Draw.init();

  // The snap interaction must be added after the Modify and Draw interactions
  // in order for its map browser event handlers to be fired first. Its handlers
  // are responsible of doing the snapping.
  var snap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: vector_layer.getSource()
  });
  mapPrincipal.addInteraction(snap);
```

Aqui é o código que está no botão que cria o polígono:

```
        Draw.setActive(true, 'Polygon');
        Modify.setActive(false);
```

Aqui é o código que está no botão que altera o polígono que já está gravado n banco:

```
        Modify.setActive(true);
        Modify.setStyle(elevatorias[chave].color);
        vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
            name: 'my_vectorlayer',
            geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(elevatorias[chave].coords)
        }));
```

`elevatorias` é a variável array que recebeu os polígonos que estão no banco.

Então é isso senhores.